# Why does adding in a blank plot_ly graph allow subsequent plot_ly plots to be printed in r markdown?

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, knitr

I am making an HTML presentation on certain crops in certain states with R Markdown and R Plot_ly.
I have made functions that draw the appropriate plots for each argument. When I tested the functionality of the functions on single states, the presentation knitted together well and displayed all desired plots.
Here are the chunks where I call the function that plots the ELRs for Illinois before looping over the crops for the state (Illinois) and using the crop id (i) as the argument for the function that draws the plots for each crop and the function that draws the plots for each variable in the model that deals with the crop:

````
 ## 2020 Illinois ELR's and Explanatory Variables{.tabset}  
    ### All ELR's {.tabset .tabset-pills}
    <h3>Estimated Loss Ratios</h3>
    ``` {r echo = FALSE, out.width="1200px", out.height="900px"}
    DrawStatePlot(13)
    ```

    ```{r Crop-and-Variable-loop, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
        for (i in names(StCrCodes["Illinois"][[1]][]))
                {
                    cat(paste0("\n\n### ",subset(CrCdsNms,CommodityCode %in% c(StCrCodes["Illinois"][[1]][i]))$CommodityName," {.tabset .tabset-pills}\n"))
                    cat(paste0("\n\n#### ELR's\n<h3>Estimated Loss Ratio's</h3>\n"))
                    paste0("\n```{r echo = FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}")
                    print(DrawStCrPlot("Illinois",i))
                    paste0("\n```")
                    
                    cat(paste0("\n\n#### Explanatory Variable's\n<h3>Explanatory Variable's</h3>\n"))
                    paste0("\n```{r echo = FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}\n")
                    print(DrawExVarPlot("Illinois",i))
                    paste0("\n```")
                }
      ```
````

I then added a dropdown menu to select each state dynamically and a loop to print the statewide ELRs and crop data for every state:

````
# 2020 ELR's and Explanatory Variables for States{.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

```{r, "State_Crop_ExplVar_Loop", results="asis", echo=FALSE}
        for (h in names(StCrCodes))
        {
            cat(paste0("\n\n## 2020 ",h," ELR's and Explanatory Variables{.tabset}\n")) 
            cat(paste0("\n\n### All ELR's {.tabset .tabset-pills}\n<h3>Estimated Loss Ratios</h3>\n"))
            paste0("\n```{r  echo=FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}")
            print(DrawStatePlot(h))
            paste0("\n```")
    
            for (i in names(StCrCodes[h][[1]][]))
            {
                cat(paste0("\n\n### ",subset(CrCdsNms,CommodityCode %in% c(StCrCodes["Illinois"][[1]][i]))$CommodityName," {.tabset .tabset-pills}\n"))
                cat(paste0("\n\n#### ELR's\n<h3>Estimated Loss Ratio's</h3>\n"))
                paste0("\n```{r echo = FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}")
                print(DrawStCrPlot(h,i))
                paste0("\n```")
                
                cat(paste0("\n\n#### Explanatory Variable's\n<h3>Explanatory Variable's</h3>\n"))
                paste0("\n```{r echo = FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}\n")
                print(DrawExVarPlot(h,i))
                paste0("\n```")
            }
        }
    ```
````

however, the graphs no longer showed up when I tried knitting this until I added an empty ploty graph with `plotly_empty()` like so:

````
# 2020 ELR's and Explanatory Variables for States{.tabset .tabset-dropdown}
```{r, "Graphics_Device_Workaround", echo=FALSE,include=F}
        plotly_empty()
```

```{r, "State_Crop_ExplVar_Loop", results="asis", echo=FALSE}
    for (h in names(StCrCodes))
    {
        cat(paste0("\n\n## 2020 ",h," ELR's and Explanatory Variables{.tabset}\n")) 
        cat(paste0("\n\n### All ELR's {.tabset .tabset-pills}\n<h3>Estimated Loss Ratios</h3>\n"))
        paste0("\n```{r  echo=FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}")
        print(DrawStatePlot(h))
        paste0("\n```")

        for (i in names(StCrCodes[h][[1]][]))
        {
            cat(paste0("\n\n### ",subset(CrCdsNms,CommodityCode %in% c(StCrCodes["Illinois"][[1]][i]))$CommodityName," {.tabset .tabset-pills}\n"))
            cat(paste0("\n\n#### ELR's\n<h3>Estimated Loss Ratio's</h3>\n"))
            paste0("\n```{r echo = FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}")
            print(DrawStCrPlot(h,i))
            paste0("\n```")
            
            cat(paste0("\n\n#### Explanatory Variable's\n<h3>Explanatory Variable's</h3>\n"))
            paste0("\n```{r echo = FALSE, out.width='1200px', out.height='900px'}\n")
            print(DrawExVarPlot(h,i))
            paste0("\n```")
        }
    }
```
````

Why does there need to be a plot_ly() graph outside of a for loop for the rest of the graphs to show up in the knitted presentation? I tried getting the same result with `tagList` with no luck and I am quite confused.

Comment: It has to do with how RMarkdown becomes an HTML script. From Yihui, the author of these packages, "the metadata about HTML dependencies is not recorded." Essentially, R Markdown output tends to make everything images. If it wasn't rendered before that translation (for lack of a better word) it doesn't get translated ever. I am definitely not anywhere near that person's level of understanding, though.

Comment: Ah, fantastic. There is so much documentation that I have a hard time finding the exact answer I want, especially when it comes to such niche questions like this.

Comment: @Kat, did you find this in the [online R Markdown Book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/)?

Comment: That book looks like a good resource. However, I read that in a ticket on Github. I tried to find it again so I could send you the link but wasn't able to figure out where I found it. However, I did find that `knitr` was updated on 1/1/22 and this dependency issue is a focal point of the update. May be worth it to see if you have the latest version. ([Read about it here](https://rdrr.io/github/yihui/knitr/f/NEWS.md).)

Comment: @Kat I try to update my packages once a week so I should. I will read through this. Thanks again!